# 403 forbidden error with Nginx despite permissions being set

Tags: nginx, centos

My actual problem is that Nginx is not able to render pages (403 forbidden) despite the permissions being set to 755 for nginx:nginx.

I am using the following command...

```
[root@wfe1 user1]# strace -p 26934 -e trace=file
Process 26934 attached
stat("/home/user1/site3/index.html", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=6, ...}) = 0
open("/home/user1/site3/index.html", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The output as you can see is Permission Denied. I would like to know which user account was used to access the file? How can I dig in further?

```
[root@wfe1 user1]# ls -al site3
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nginx nginx   23 Mar  6 06:12 .
drwx------. 5 user1 user1 4096 Mar  6 06:12 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 nginx nginx    6 Mar  6 06:12 index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the nginx access logs to see where things are failing

Use `ps aux | grep nginx` to see which user nginx is running as.

Make sure you have the correct "allow all" permissions set in your nginx config / location stanza.